# Karate array field become object when it is returned from JS function

Tags: arrays, object, karate

I'm trying to compare response with predefined JSON (expected) generated by JS function.
JS:

```
    function(fleetId) {
        var result = {};
        result.name = "TestConnection";
        result.fleetId = fleetId;
        result.connectionConfigDefault = { "configParameters": [{ "keyName": "N/A", "value": "testValue" }], "id": 4 }
        return result;
    }
```

Test:

```
...
Then match connection.response ==
                                       """
                                           {
                                            connectionConfigDefault: '#(connectionJson.connectionConfigDefault)',
                                            fleetId: '#(connectionJson.fleetId)',
                                            id: '#number',
                                            name: '#(connectionJson.name)'
                                           }
                                       """
```

JS return:

```
"connectionConfigDefault": {
    "configParameters": { "0": { "keyName": "N/A", "value": "testValue" } }
    }
```

instead of expected:

```
"connectionConfigDefault": { 
"configParameters": [{ "keyName": "N/A", "value": "testValue" }]
}
```

P.S. I read similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50580415/karate-array-field-become-object), but the answer did not help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do 1 thing..
before returning your json in javascript convert it to string using `configParameters = JSON.stringify(configParameters)`
now call this function from feature file, with json variable.

```
In function "function(fleetId)"
```

before returning result convert it to string by typing

```
result = JSON.stringify(result)
```

here you will call that function from karate

```
* json fleetId = function(fleetId)
* print fleetId
```

I hope this will resolve your question

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is this weird bug in the JDK that you normally never run into unless you start doing nested arrays in JS: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/demos/js-arrays.feature#L44

The workaround here is to do JSON construction using Karate not JS:

EDIT: see using `read()` below, instead of "in-line":

```
# * def conf = { "configParameters": [{ "keyName": "N/A", "value": "testValue" }], "id": 4 }
* def fun = 
"""
function(fleetId) {
    var result = {};
    result.name = "TestConnection";
    result.fleetId = fleetId;
    var conf = read('conf.json');
    result.connectionConfigDefault = conf;
    return result;
}
"""
```

Since Karate has so many nice ways, why don't you use those:

```
* def fleetId = 1

* set temp
| path    | value            |
| name    | 'TestConnection' |
| fleetId | fleetId          |
| connectionConfigDefault | { "configParameters": [{ "keyName": "N/A", "value": "testValue" }], "id": 4 } |

* print temp
```

Comment: Thank you @PeterThomas. I use JS to create an entity's JSON (with only required parameters) and reuse it in many cases: create a simple or custom entity. Therefore I need to keep it in a separate file.

Comment: @RomanL. note that if you load json via `read()` that also works fine

Comment: I know, but I need build (pass fleetId, generate unique name) JSON, not just read from the file.

Comment: @RomanL. relax. see my edit, just use `read()` *even* in a JS snippet and problem solved :)

Comment: Adding one more karate way to return from JavaScript function `return Java.type("com.intuit.karate.JsonUtils").toJson(result)` to avoid this issue

Comment: IMPORTANT UPDATE: this is fixed in 0.9.3 - https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/787