# karate javaScript array format

Tags: javascript, karate

Here is my javascript which prepares json which I will use for matching an api response

```
var squArray = []
for (j = loopincri; j < (loopincri + skuCount); j++) {
    var skuJson = {
        "skuCode": skuCodes[j],
        "quantity": quantity
    }
    squArray.push(skuJson)
}
```

when I am printing this is coming like:

```
{
  "0": {
    "sku_code": "50",
    "quantityNO": 2,
    "min": 550,
    "max": 13000,
    "dtePrice": {
      "0": {
        "date": "2019-04-11",
        "listPrice": 6600,
        "salePrice": 3870
      },
      "1": {
        "date": "2019-04-12",
        "listPrice": 6600,
        "salePrice": 3870
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I want the result to be like

```
[
  {
    "sku_code": "50",
    "quantityNO": 2,
    "min": 550,
    "max": 13000,
    "dtePrice": [
      {
        "date": "2019-04-11",
        "listPrice": 6600,
        "salePrice": 3870
      },
      {
        "date": "2019-04-12",
        "listPrice": 6600,
        "salePrice": 3870
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Can you please help me out with this?
As the response of the api is in the format I want

Comment: `squArray` is an array. How does it become an object?

Comment: It becomes object in karate tool

Comment: Oh, never mind then

Comment: Can you help me to fix it?

Comment: I think it is because of this issue which @ptrthomas mentioned in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/q/54256534/8615449. but not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be workaround for overcoming that jdk bug discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54256766/8615449

Instead of returning your object directly, 
try,

```
return Java.type("com.intuit.karate.JsonUtils").toJson(squArray)
```

I know this return JSON in a string format, you can cast it in your feature by

```
* json myJson = JsFunction()
```

here `JsFunction()` is the function that you created above which returns that json value.

Comment: I tried this it is converting it into array but it's adding "/" in my values
thus the output becomes
"[{\"skuCode\":\"58\",\"quantity\":2},{\"skuCode\":\"60\",\"quantity\":2}]"}]"

Comment: I am sorry your question and example is not enough to replicate this.

Comment: gr8, would you like to update your answer here so that it will be helpful for people referring this post

Comment: I used JSON.stringify() to convert it to string and then i returned this to json variable

Comment: cool. but be advised that `JSON.stringify()` in **karate** only works when you have pure javascript data member.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an issue with arrays if you do too much in JS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54256766/143475 - so if you do `karate.read()` to create the chunks of JSON, it should start working.

My recommendation is avoid using JS as far as possible, try to use Karate natives for looping and transformation etc. For example:

```
* def skuCodes = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
* def nums = []
* eval for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) nums.add(~~i)
* def fun = function(x){ return { skuCode: skuCodes[x], array: read('array.json') } }
* def json = karate.map(nums, fun)
```

Yes, using `read()` is a slight inconvenience, but note that you can use embedded expressions within a JSON file. This will be fixed in a future version of Karate.

Comment: What are contents of array.json here ?

Answer (score -1):

Don't know about karate JS. But if karate JS is converting your array to object then you can reconvert to array. As you can see that the resulting object is arraylike which can easily be converted to array using "Array.from(queryObject)" method.
Modification :-

```
var squArray = []
for(j=loopincri ; j<(loopincri+skuCount); j++){
        var skuJson = {"skuCode":skuCodes[j],
                       "quantity":quantity};
        squArray.push(skuJson);
    }
let squArray = Array.from(squArray);
```