# How to generate JSON with N objects in array using Karate framework?

Tags: json, karate

I have next json object:

```
{
  "email": "api.test@cool.io",
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "birthday": "1982-08-30",
  "createdAt": "2015-10-02T08:23:53Z",
  "gender": "male",
  "businessUnit": "DE"
}
```

And I want put it in my array named "udpated" N times:

```
{ updated : [], deleted : []}
```

Would you be so kind to tell how could I do this using Karate framework? How that might be done in elegant way?

I have tried pure JS like this

```
 Scenario: read json within a js function1
        * def getId = function(){ return java.util.UUID.randomUUID() + '' }
        * def x = read('classpath:data/user.json')
        * eval
        """
         var body = { updated : [], deleted : []};
         var foo = function(){
            var uuid = getId();
            x.id = uuid;
            x.email = 'api.test+' + uuid + '@cool.io';
            body.updated.push(x);
            body.updated.push(x);
          }
          foo();
          karate.set('temp', body);
        """
        * print temp
```

but got as a result not an Array but a Map. Here is my result :

```
15:58:45.580 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] {
  "updated": {
    "0": {
      "email": "api.test+543d3448-7726-4bb3-8762-e593fb2c5435@cool.io",
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "birthday": "1982-08-30",
      "createdAt": "2015-10-02T08:23:53Z",
      "gender": "male",
      "businessUnit": "DE",
      "id": "543d3448-7726-4bb3-8762-e593fb2c5435"
    }
  },
  "deleted": {
    "0": "#ref:java.util.LinkedHashMap"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this makes sense. Yes there is an annoying edge case bug for JS nested arrays coming back as JSON (Map-s). There is a quick fix solution that you can find in the comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54256766/143475

Just think of anything in the Karate world as Java (prefer this) and anything within a JS function as pure JS - but which can refer to an existing Java-flavoured variable. There are multiple elegant ways to do this - but this is what I came up with quickly.

```
* def getId = function(){ return java.util.UUID.randomUUID() + '' }
* def x = { foo: 'bar' }
* def body = { updated : [], deleted : [] };
* def fun =
"""
function() {
  var uuid = getId();
  x.id = uuid;
  x.email = 'api.test+' + uuid + '@cool.io';
  body.updated.add(x);
  body.deleted.add(x);
}
"""
* eval fun()
* copy body = body
* print body
```

The `copy` gets rid of the duplicate object reference getting serialized properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! works fine for me now.
@Peter Thomas, do you think there are other more elegant variants of solving this? Not using pure JS i mean.

Comment: @Denis actually you give me an idea to add a `karate.repeat()` API to add to the ones here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms - see the other answer I linked for examples (look at the whole file)

Comment: appreciation for the great support!